# Sort an ArrayList using Comparator Interface

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, comparator

I am not getting the sorted list by using comparator. I have tried to solve it using Collections.sort(), then only I am getting the correct answer.

```
public class CompratorProgram2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> l= new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(232);
            l.add(524);
            l.add(111);
            l.add(433);

Comparator<Integer> ac= new CompratorProgram();

            Collections.sort(l, ac);
       // Collections.sort(l);

        for(int i: l)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Second Class

```
public class CompratorProgram implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2){
        if(o1>02)
            return 1;
        else
 return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this as output- 232, 524, 111, 433

Comment: It's `o2`, not `02`

Comment: That `compare` method is violating its [contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-): *The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.* The method fails when `x` and `y` are **equal**, since `compare(x, y)` and `compare(y, x)` would both return `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java version 8 feature lambda expression.so Collections no needed List has sort() method that accept Comparator.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    integerList.add(3333);
    integerList.add(3);
    integerList.add(55);
    integerList.add(2);

    integerList.sort((i1, i2) -> i1.compareTo(i2));

    System.out.println(integerList);
}
```

the output will be:
[2, 3, 55, 3333]

Comment: There is no need to specify a comparator like `(i1, i2) -> i1.compareTo(i2)`. You can just use `integerList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or even `integerList.sort(null)`.